# python のライブラリで、 ruby でいう rake を実現するものはありますか

Tags: python

python のライブラリで、 ruby でいう rake を実現するものはありますか。

具体的には、以下を実現したいです。

- タスクを定義し、それを実行する
- タスクには依存関係が定義できる
- ファイルの存在・ないし更新日時を、タスクの依存関係に組み込むことができる
  (Makefile のように)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SCons http://www.scons.org/ はどうですか。使った事は無いですがPythonでMake代替というとよく引き合いに出てきます。